# Window.onbeforeunload no FireFOX

Tags: jquery

Ao utiliza "window.onbeforeunload" no firefox, ele retorna apenas uma mensagem genérica conforme a imagem a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de eu customizar esta mensagem em um "modal" no firefox?

Comment: O máximo que você pode fazer é colocar uma mensagem personalizada simples, sem formatação nem nada (i.e. uma string). Todo o resto é por conta do *browser*. Antigamente os sites abusavam, abrindo novas popups logo antes de serem fechados, etc, então hoje os *browsers* só dão uma opção simples e padronizada, sem muita liberdade pra desviar disso.

Comment: No Chrome, IE, Safari e Opera, você especificar uma mensagem assim: `window.onbeforeunload = function() { return 'sua mensagem aqui'; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente, **não** é possível sobrescrever a mensagem padrão no Firefox.

O evento `beforeunload` utiliza um método interno do navegador para interromper o fechamento/navegação. Na função atribuída ao evento, você deve retornar uma string que será adicionada à mensagem padrão do navegador. Isso em todos os navegadores MENOS o Firefox, que só exibe sua própria mensagem.

Documentação do evento no Mozilla Developer Network:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Documentação no MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado.