# Abrir Modal no Fechamento da Aba

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, 
Gostaria de abrir uma janela modal no momento que o usuário tentar fechar o navegador e questionar se realmente quer sair.

Sei que poderia fazer isso com beforeunload, mas queria controlar para caso ele permaneça não forçar e aparecer o banner novamente.

Obrigado.

Comment: Para além de que é má ideia impedir utilizadores de fazerem o que querem (fechar o navegador) há limitações nalguns browsers do que podes perguntar/mostrar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60044/129

Comment: @Sergio Realmente é um coisa ruim, mas foi o que me solicitaram. Sobre a mensagem sei que ele é exibida, mesmo assim preciso fazer isso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Cria uma variável e a armazene no localStorage;

Na primeira vez que usuário for sair da página, aparece o modal, então, nesse momento, já salva algum dado no localStorage, na próxima vez que for sair, ele verifica se a variável existe, se existir sai normalmente.

**Execute este código e depois tente fechar a página:**

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(){

if(!localStorage.getItem('sair')){
    localStorage.setItem('sair',1)
  return false; 
}
}
```

Funciona com ctrl+f4, alt+f4; ctrl+w, clicando no botão de fechar da janela.